# React Component adds classNames which aren't recognized because of imported css modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

Currently working on a large project that uses React and CSS Modules. I want to implement 'react-anything-sortable' on a bunch of list items.

So far the implementation has gone to a standstill because 'react-anything-sortable' adds the following classes to any child inside the 'react-anything-component': .ui-sortable, .ui-sortable-item, .ui-draggable and .ui-sortable-placeholder. I assume these are classes which are passed for the 'react-anything-sortable' to recognize which DOM elements are being dragged, placed, etc.

I import my List component's styles by referencing to a .scss file like so:

```
import styles from './WidgetList.scss'
```

To use the styles on a component, you would need to add styles.CLASS to use a class:

```
<div className={styles.container}>Something</div>
```

Therefore, it's understandable that the .ui-sortable being placed by 'react-anything-sortable' has no way of referencing a stylesheet since it doesn't add .styles.

[image]
One can easily see how other div elements have a 'hashed' className (indicating the class in their respective css modules have been found), however, the div with the ui-sortable only has the class but no way of accessing the .scss file containing the style properties of .ui-sortable

How do I fix this?

**EDIT**: Here's how I'm implementing it

WidgetList.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ThinScrollbar from 'components/Scrollbars/ThinScrollbar';
import PureComponent from '../PureComponent';

import Sortable from 'react-anything-sortable';
import { sortable } from 'react-anything-sortable';
import styles from './WidgetList.scss';

@sortable
class WidgetListItem extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div {...this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class WidgetList extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    handleSort(data) {
        this.setState({
            result: data.join(' ')
        });
        console.log(this.state.result)
    }

    toggleCheckbox(evt) {
        console.log(evt)
    }

    render() {
        let items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        // TODO: move widget creation to its own component <WidgetItem/>
        const widgetItems = items.map(i => {
            return (
                <WidgetListItem className="vertical" sortData={i} key={i}> //<--- this is where .ui-sortable-item is added on render
                    <div className={styles.item} i={i}>
                        <i className={styles.fa}></i>{`Widget ${i}`}
                        <div className={styles.checkbox} onClick={this.toggleCheckbox}></div>
                    </div>
                </WidgetListItem>
            )
        })
        return <div className={styles.container}>
            <ThinScrollbar>
                <Sortable onSort={::this.handleSort} className="vertical-container" direction="vertical"> //<--- this is where .ui-sortable is added on render
                    {widgetItems}
                </Sortable>
            </ThinScrollbar>
        </div>
    }
}
```

WidgetList.scss

```
@import "../../theme/variables";

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc((100% - 335px) / 2);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    padding: 0 4px 0 10px;
}

.item {
    border-left: 5px solid #46484C;
    background-color: #303236;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: #34363b;
}

.item:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.fa:before {
    content: '\f07b';
}

.checkbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    background: url('img/checkboxes.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.activeCheckbox {
    composes: checkbox;
    background-position: 0 -20;
}

.ui-sortable {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.ui-sortable:before,
.ui-sortable:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.ui-sortable:after {
    clear: both;
}

.ui-sortable .ui-sortable-item {
    float: left;
    cursor: move;
}

.ui-sortable .ui-sortable-item.ui-sortable-dragging {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1688;
}

.ui-sortable .ui-sortable-placeholder {
    display: none;
}

.ui-sortable .ui-sortable-placeholder.visible {
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}

.vertical-container {
    width: 200px;
    height:500px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    background-color: red;
}

.vertical.ui-sortable-item {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px #eee solid;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Provide code of your component where you insert className

Comment: Thanks for replying, here's the code. There you can see that some elements have className={styles.item} etc. But the other classNames are inserted by 'react-anything-sortable' into <Sortable> and <WidgetListItem>

Comment: check console.log(styles)

Comment: returns all .css classes as object property of styles object. Looking for a way to tell 'react-anything-sortable' so access the ones in styles, and not just place its own. (I think)

Comment: className undefined only on WidgetListItem ? or on childrens too?

Comment: it's not undefined. It's just that the classNames that <Sortable> component adds can't find the style because they're not prepended by 'styles' to access the scss

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the `ui-sortable` className, i.e. you can't use css modules you can instead export those classNames as 'global' classes:

```
/* Will be hashed */
.activeCheckbox {
    background-position: 0 -20px;
}

/* Will be left as 'ui-sortable' */
:global .ui-sortable {
    display: block;
}
```

If you have a combination of global and local classNames in the same selector you can also specify individual classNames as 'global':

```
/* 'ui-sortable' will be left as 'ui-sortable', 'bar' will be hashed */
:global(.ui-sortable) .bar {
    display: block;
}
```